# Flashing CM13 on Galaxy Tab GT-P3100

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung, rom-flashing

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, GT-P3100. It has quite an outdated firmware and is bulky with loads of unnecessary apps.
I wish to flash it with CM13.

Now firstly my device isn't rooted. Secondly I have no prior experience in rooting/flashing. Lastly, I don't have an SD card, but do have a PC (and of course internet access to download all the necessary tools).

Under such circumstances, is there a way for me to flash CM13 without having to purchase or lend an SD card?
Also, is it worth the flash? Will CM13 run at all, given about 500 mb or RAM is at most free when the device is idle? If not, what are my alternatives, if any?

Edit: I have the zips for CM13 and Gapps.

Answer (score 2):

**Caution: I have rooted my device for the first time, I have no prior experience in rooting. Continue at your own risk.**

I am not sure about the RAM part, but we can flash the custom ROM from the internal SD card too. The following link is for explains the installation process for Installing CM 10.1 on Galaxy Tab2, however, we can follow the same steps for GT-P3100:

https://www.droidviews.com/how-to-install-cyanogenmod-10-1-rom-on-samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7-0-and-tab-2-10-1/

I also followed the following youtube video and downloaded the zips for CM and Gapp from the link in the description:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYZUKqGPNcE

Also, I had an error while installing the Gapp(it got aborted). I fixed it using the default option in the menu.

Finally, the device is working properly, there was no issue due to the error encountered during Gapp installation.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Happy to tell you that I managed to flash CM13 after considerable toil, and it works about fine. Occasional system crashes and restarts, yes, unfortunately. Even Chrome lags everytime. And yes, I could flash it from internal storage with the help of CWM. Nevertheless, thanks!